# Google Play Game Services and LibGDX, how to integrate without showing a title bar?

Tags: libgdx, screen-orientation, titlebar, google-play-games

Successfully connecting while using this code:

[Tutorial to add Google Play Services to LibGDX](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u1070589/blog/?p=202)

However, I now have the android title bar visible.  I have tried nailing down what exactly causes the title bar to show (and am using verbatim the code from the tutorial).

I think it is in having a MainActivity constructor in the mix, somehow, this bypasses the LibGDX calls that request noTitle.

So, I tried next to add in the Theme feature of NoTitleBar in my Manifest, and that works, but somehow, I now have orientation changes occurring (which is not what it says in the manifest)

Can anyone see what I need to do in either my Main project or Android project to

1) not have a title bar
2) not allow for orientation changes
3) have the hookup for Google Play Services

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pgs.libgdx.liars.dice"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is relevant code from Android Project:

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements GameHelperListener, GoogleInterface {

private GameHelper aHelper;

private OnLeaderboardScoresLoadedListener theLeaderboardListener;

public MainActivity(){
    aHelper = new GameHelper(this);
    aHelper.enableDebugLog(true, "MYTAG");

    //create a listener for getting raw data back from leaderboard
    theLeaderboardListener = new OnLeaderboardScoresLoadedListener() {

        public void onLeaderboardScoresLoaded(int arg0, LeaderboardBuffer arg1,
                LeaderboardScoreBuffer arg2) {

            System.out.println("In call back");

            for(int i = 0; i < arg2.getCount(); i++){
                System.out.println(arg2.get(i).getScoreHolderDisplayName() + " : " + arg2.get(i).getDisplayScore());
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = false;
    aHelper.setup(this);
    initialize(new LiarsDiceGame(this), cfg);
}
```

and the Main relevant code:

```
public LiarsDiceGame(){

}

public LiarsDiceGame(GoogleInterface anInterface ) {
    platformInterface = anInterface;
    //platformInterface.Login();
}

@Override
public void create() {      
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 512, 275);

    sprite = new Sprite(region);
    sprite.setSize(0.9f, 0.9f * sprite.getHeight() / sprite.getWidth());
    sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
    sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth()/2, -sprite.getHeight()/2);
}
```

Everything else is exactly as it when setting up a LibGDX project using the gdx-setup-ui.jar

Comment: In looking at the logcat, I do see where it mentions "Content already displayed, cannot request FEATURE_NOTITLE."  I have tried to look through the backend, but cannot see why this is popping up as written.  No content is being called, unless (I think) because of the call to MainActivity, the Manifest is utilized by android, but then why won't orientation get locked down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with the syntax of your manifest file, in this line:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

The angle bracket at the end of the line should not be there.

Comment: ugh... nothing that I could see in Eclipse (no error reported, anyway)  Working like a champ now!